# React redux componentでglobal stateをinput値として使用していますがinputで入力できない

Tags: reactjs, redux

componenntでglobal stateを使って表示しているですが、画面上にそのinputの値が変えられない。
値を変えるために新しいactionを発行してinputのonChangeとbindすると変更できるようになりましたが、
これではinputごとに新しいactionを作らないといけないことになるのでこういうやり方では違う気がします。

以下はcomponent PlayerData.jsのコードです。

```
const PlayerData = props => {
    const { playerData, fetchPlayerData } = props//ここでreducerからstateを取る
    //const [playerAp, setPlayerAp] = React.useState(0)//ローカルで管理したい
    ...
    const handleSearchButton = React.useCallback(() => {
        fetchPlayerData(playerId) //検索ボタンを押して検索してglobal stateであるplayerDataを更新する 
        //setPlayerAp(playerData.ap) //ここでlocal stateに保存したいですが、この時点ではplayerDataはまだnullです
    })
    ...
​
    const renderPlayerData = () => {
        ...
        <TableCell>{playerData.name}</TableCell>
        <TableCell>
            <Input 
　　　　　　　　　value={playerData.ap} //global stateの値を表示、これを画面上に変更できるようにしたい
               //value={playerAp}//最終的にこうなりたいです
　　　　　　　　　name="ap"className={classes.ap_input} 
　　　　　　　　　id="input_playerap" />
            <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button} onClick={handleApSetButton}>
                Set AP
            </Button>
        </TableCell>
        ...
    }

    return (
    <>
      ...
      <div>
        <FormControl className={classes.input}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="input_playerid">プレイヤーID</InputLabel>
          <Input
            value={playerId}
            onChange={handlePlayerIdChanged}
            id="input_playerid"
          />
        </FormControl>
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          className={classes.button}
          onClick={handleSearchButton}
        >
          検索
        </Button>
      </div>
      {renderPlayerData()}
    </>
  )
}
​
PlayerData.propTypes = {
  playerData: PropTypes.object,
  fetchPlayerData: PropTypes.func
}
```

action Player.jsのコード

```
export async function fetchPlayerData(dispatch, playerId) {

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PLAYER_DATA_LOADING 
    })

    const requestBody = JSON.stringify({})

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_PLAYER_DATA_FINISHED, 
        payload: getResponse('/admin/api/player/get', playerId, requestBody)
    })
}

const getResponse = async (url, playerId, request_body) => {


    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx',
            'PlayerID': playerId,
        },

        credentials: 'same-origin',
        body: request_body 
    })

    const response_body = await response.json()
    return response_body
}
```

reducer PlayerDataRedux.jsのコード

```
const initialState = {
    fetchLoading: false,
    playerData: null,
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_PLAYER_DATA_LOADING: 
            return {
                ...state, 
                fetchLoading: true,
            } 
        case FETCH_PLAYER_DATA_FINISHED: 
            return {
                ...state,
                playerData: action.payload,
                fetchLoading: false,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

container PlayerDataRedux.jsのコード

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as Player from '../../actions/Player'
import PlayerDataComponent from '../../components/Player/PlayerDataRedux'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    playerData: state.PlayerDataRedux.playerData,
    fetchLoading: state.PlayerDataRedux.fetchLoading,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchPlayerData: playerId => Player.fetchPlayerData(dispatch, playerId),
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(PlayerDataComponent)
```

Comment: stateを変更している箇所([すなわちreducer](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions))の実装がどうなっているかの情報が必要かなと感じました。

Comment: 他のaction,reducer,containernのコードも貼りました。

Comment: 自分的には画面で編集できるデータはlocal stateで管理したいんですが、データ検索した後どうやってreducerのstateにあるデータをcomponentのstateに渡せるのが分からないです。renderPlayerDataの最初でsetStateで保存しようとしていたけど、re-renderなんかのloopエラーが発生しまた。